# Rails Production Database Tables Empty However Application is Working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, production

I am new to Rails development. I deployed an application to Heroku. From my terminal I ran `rails db`, which enables me to query to development database. I am able to view the data in the development environment database just fine. I can also add users in the development environment and see that another record was added to the database (all is good in that world).

However, in my production environment the tables are all empty. I deployed to Herou (which worked) then I added a few users in the production application. Then I ran `rails db production` to load the production database. Then when I query the production database I see that the Users table is empty despite having added user to it.

I am assuming the problem is something about loading the latest production data. I am assuming this because the production application works just fine. I can sign up new users and using those new records sign them into the application. This tells me that the tables exist in the production environment and that data is written to them.

Why when I run `rails db production` and query the production database are the tables empty? Is there some way to load the most recent production environment or is there something else I am missing? I am not sure if it is relevant but I am using PostgreSQL in both my development and production environments.